# how to copy 64 bit integer from host to device in cuda?

Tags: cuda

I need to copy 64 bit integer data from host to device memory.
Both of them are declared as `unsigned __int64` and i used `cudaMemcpyToSymbol()`.
By checking with Parallel Nsight, the copied data is shown as a negative integer.
I guess the most significant bit of the lower 4 bytes is treated as a sign bit which is not supposed to be.
Can anybody give me any direction to come up with this?

Answer (score 3):

Oh, I found the reason.
Though every 64-bit data manipulation works fine, Parallel Nsight does not recognize any 64 bit integer. 
It was Nsight problem. It really sucks.
This incomplete debugger made me waste time.